# How can I let a null values pass in a sam template if it is in an API Gateway DefinitionBody as a response example

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-api-gateway, openapi, aws-sam

I have an OpenAPI 3.0.1 file and conforming to the standard it contains some examples responses for endpoints. Now since some of the parameters in the response are set to be `nullable` there are some examples which look as follows:

```
examples:
  account_not_verified:
    value:
      eamil: 'test@example.com'
      verification: '0'
      name: null
```

Since the `name` parameters is set up like this:

```
name:
    type: string
    nullable: true
```

I would assume that having a null value in the example response is valid by the open api standard. When I put this into the Swagger Editor is does not show any errors or warnings. But as soon as I include the OpenAPI file into my sam template to be used to configure an HTTP API Gateway like so:

```
ApiGateway:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::HttpApi
  Properties:
    StageName: !Ref Stage
    FailOnWarnings: true
    DefinitionBody:
      Fn::Transform:
        Name: AWS::Include
        Parameters:
          Location: ./oapi.yml
```

Cloud formation gives me the following error:

```
[/Resources/ApiGateway/Type/Body/paths/***/content/application/json/examples/ch_account_not_verified/value/name] 'null' values are not allowed in templates
```

Is there any way to allow this `null` value to exist in the example response or do I have to use some different method to indicate the `null` value in the example?

Comment: You are not alone; I am dealing with the same issue right now.

Answer (score 1):

So with some trial and error, I was able to define it to allow strings and nulls, at least for a SAM template RequestBody.  I am assuming API gateway uses JSON validation under the sheets, so if you define this in JSONSchema , for something like AWS power-tools validation, for example:

```
  "properties": {
    "spouse_first_name": {
    "$id": "#/properties/spouse_first_name",
    "type": ["string", "null"],
    "title": "The spouse_first_name",
    "maxLength": 100
    }
  }
```

Then the equivalent syntax in SAM template YAML would be:

```
   MyRequestModel:
     type: object
     properties:
       spouse_first_name:
         type: string, null
         maxLength: 100
```

I just tested this and it seems to allow both strings and nulls.

- In the case of body validation, Don't forget to add 'ValidateBody: true' in your SAM template to force API gateway to validate your payload:

  ```
    RequestModel:
      Model: MyRequestModel
         ValidateBody: true
  ```
- I realize this is not an apples to apples answer, but the take away is that you should be able to define it in comma separated values in YAML